# What is this trumpet sound that is heard during sports events?

Tags: media

During sports events, there's a "[trumpet sound](https://vocaroo.com/i/s1iuX4pRcoAT)" which is played in game time, particularly in the NBA when team is on attack / ball possession. The same sound is used by default in the NBA 2K14 video game as well. What does this sound mean?

Comment: Could you explain how this is different from [your previous question which you chose to delete](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/21139/trumpet-sound-in-hockey-nba)?

Comment: @PhilipKendall
Yes, i can. 
This question is with sound file added. This questioin has a different structure than that first :)

Comment: For reference, it is preferred to edit your existing question rather than deleting and posting a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sound is a [bugle call](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Kg9f_z0PDA) known as "Charge." This short music clip can be heard at different sporting events. From a sports perspective, this sound is intended for the players (and fans) to take action.

For more information, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_(bugle_call)).